# Checking instance of Sibling class

Tags: java, inheritance

As we know that we can use `instanceof` operator to check whether object A is an instance of class A. Similarly, I was wondering whether is there anyway we can check whether object A is an instance of class B, where both, class A and class B extends X. ie Classes A and B are siblings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood you, but I am assuming here that you don't know X, or that you want to find the answer for any X.

Well, all classes are siblings, as in, they all have `Object` as a common ancestor, so your method would always return true.

What you might want to do is check out what is the closest ancestor for two classes, which you could do using reflection to get all parent classes, as in:

```
Class superClass = arg1.getClass();
Class superSuperClass = superClass.getSuperclass();
```

And compare them all (post if you have problems with the code!)

Comment: "Well, all classes are siblings, as in, they all have Object as a common ancestor, so your method would always return true" Do you mean `instanceof` method?

Comment: @Thihara It was my udnerstanding that the OP wanted something *like* instanceof but which worked on classes with the same ancestor. Because of the Object ancestor, such method would always return true

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's the thing if you are using `instanceof` operator it will check against the the second argument's type. For example

```
Interface X{};
Class A implements X;
Class B implements X;

Object a=new A();
Object b=new B();
```

In the above hierarchy  `a instanceof X` and `b instanceof X` will return `true`. But `a instanceof B` will be `false` while `a instanceof A` will be `true`.

So if you just want to see if Object a is an instance of Class B `a instanceof B` will suffice regardless of which interfaces the classes implement.